# Python - How would a person open every .ppm file in a directory

Tags: python, ppm

```
import os
import glob

path = input("Please enter the directory you want to get the files from. -> ")

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.ppm')):
    open("r", encoding="utf-8")
```

I am trying to open all .ppm files in a user given directory.

Comment: What is `open("r", encoding="utf-8")` supposed to do? You never pass in a file to open, but only the mode and encoding...

Comment: `ppm` is an image file? If so can also look into using image processing module, like pillow for working with image files.

Answer (score 2):

You keep trying to open a file named "r". Try adding the filename.

```
import os
import glob

path = input("Please enter the directory you want to get the files from. -> ")

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.ppm')):
    file_obj = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something little.

Comment: As an aside, I'm pretty sure that .ppm is ascii not utf-8.